# OpenGl es view and uitableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, opengl-es

I have written an application using opengl es view.  Now I want to add a uitableview to display on the screen.

However I am needing some guidance on how opengl es view and the other views play together nice.

For example I have read some things that would lead me to think I need to pause the opengl view when the table is displayed.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to make these things work together or just point me to the stackoverflow question that I can't find where some guy asked the same exact thing and got an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have read about pausing the OpenGL view and that interacting with UIKit is not false at all, but it's not absolute. You have to find out for your application, but it's 100% true that with when using OpenGL ES + most of UIKit elements at the same time (displaying at the same time), your frame rate ( FPS ) will decrease drastically!

There is what I think is a very very good tutorial to mix UIKit with OpenGL ES ( with multiple Views), you can find it [here](http://gamesfromwithin.com/using-multiple-opengl-views-and-uikit)

I hope my answer is helpful for you!!

EDIT: The same author has just made a new and better tutorial of UIKit + OpenGL for GDC2010, check it out [here](http://gamesfromwithin.com/gdc-2010-the-best-of-both-worlds-using-uikit-with-opengl).